# Juego broma con powershell

Tags: powershell

Intento hacer un pequeño juego/broma con PowerShell para experimentar el lenguaje ya que soy un total novato, la idea son 5 preguntas y 3 vidas, si fallas una pregunta te la vuelve a hacer y te baja una vida, si llegas a 0 vidas pierdes y se te apaga el ordenador como castigo, si logras responder las 5 preguntas te dice enhorabuena y termina el programa

```
$apagar = $false
$vidas = 3
$nivel = 1
function apagarPC() {
   # shutdown -s -p
    $apagar = $true
    Write-Output "Apagando"
}

function cancelarApagado() {
   # shutdown -a
    $apagar = $false
}

function nivel1() {
    $pregunta1 = Read-Host "¿Cuanto es 1 + 1?"
    if($pregunta1 -eq 2) {
        Write-Output "Enhorabuena, has pasado al nivel 2"
        Write-Output "Vidas restantes: $($vidas)"
        $nivel = 2
        Write-Output $nivel
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "Vaya, has fallado... vuelvelo a intentar"
        Write-Output "Vidas restantes: $($vidas - 1)"
    }
}

function nivel2() {
    Write-Output "Este es el nivel 2"
}

while(($vidas -ne 0) -or ($vidas -eq 100)) {
    switch ($nivel) {
        1{nivel1}
        2{nivel2}
        3{nivel3}
        4{nivel4}
        5{nivel5}
        default{
            Write-Output "Has Ganado!!"
            $vidas = 100
        }
    }
}

if($vidas -ne 0) {
    apagarPC
}
```

Me gustaría hacer los niveles cada una en una función, el error que me da es que nunca sale del nivel 1, aciertes o falles
Un saludo y gracias de antemano

También si pierdes todas las vidas te de una ultima oportunidad de responder una pregunta en 30 segundos o se apaga el ordenador, si la resuelves se cancela el apagado

Comment: ¿En que momento llamas a las funciones? dentro de while ?

Comment: Dentro del while con el switch, el switch elige en que nivel está y el bucle se encarga de que se rapita hasta ganar o perder

Comment: Aunque solo está creada la funcion del nivel 1 y 2, no se si eso afecta en powershell